# How to merge two PHP' include' to one PHP 'include' aand use to a PHP Page

Tags: php

guys currently I build a web site using PHP. I connect my website to the database using web services (url). The system is run as well. Then, I separate the web services by creating other PHP files, place the web services and include the PHP file to my web site. This is also running well. Below is the code:

add_factory.php

```
<?php

    include("../../config/check.php");

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {

      $Fac_ID = $_POST['Fac_ID'];

      include("../../api/api_add_factory.php"); //include web services 1

      if(empty($queryt)){

              include("../../api/api2_add_factory.php"); //include web services 2

              if(!empty($json2)){

                header("Location:factory.php");

              }else{
                echo "
                <script>alert('Something wrong, please try again')</script>
                <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
                ";

              }
            }
      else{

          echo "
          <script>alert('The factory you want to add is already exist')</script>
          <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
          ";

      }
    }

?>
```

api_add_factory.php

```
<?php

    $url = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/selectFactory?Fac_ID=$Fac_ID";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    $queryt = $json->factoryList;

?>
```

api2_add_factory.php

```
<?php

    $url2 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/insertFactory?fac_id=$Fac_ID&fac_name=$Fac_ID";
    $data2 = file_get_contents($url2);
    $json2 = json_decode($data2);

?>
```

When you see at "add_factory.php", There's two include. Now, I want to use only single include that can call "api_add_factory.php" and "api2_add_factory.php". But I dont know how to do that since the "include" at "add_factory.php" is at different position.

Can anyone knows how to merge both include file into one and where i need to pu the include file at "add_factory.php"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to rewrite the contents of `api_add_factory.php` and `api2_add_factory.php` as functions.
This would allow you to control how and when they are called by the piece of code that includes them, rather than being executed immediately when the `include` is called.
Also, as a general rule of thumb, includes should all be called at the beginning of your file because otherwise they can become very difficult to keep track of.

So, I would say you can do something like this:

`api_add_factory.php`

```
<?php

function callApi1()
{
    $url = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/selectFactory?Fac_ID=$Fac_ID";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    return $json->factoryList;
}
```

`api2_add_factory.php`

```
<?php

function callApi2()
{
    $url2 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/insertFactory?fac_id=$Fac_ID&fac_name=$Fac_ID";
    $data2 = file_get_contents($url2);
    return json_decode($data2);
}
```

`add_factory.php`

```
<?php

include("../../config/check.php");
include("../../api/api_add_factory.php"); //include web services 2
include("../../api/api2_add_factory.php"); //include web services 2

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

  $Fac_ID = $_POST['Fac_ID'];

  $queryt = callApi1();

  if(empty($queryt)){

          $json2 = callApi2();

          if(!empty($json2)){

            header("Location:factory.php");

          }else{
            echo "
            <script>alert('Something wrong, please try again')</script>
            <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
            ";

          }
        }
  else{

      echo "
      <script>alert('The factory you want to add is already exist')</script>
      <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
      ";

  }
}
```

Actually, now that I am taking a look at my answer, I can see a possibility for a further improvement: since the contents of `api_add_factory.php` and `api2_add_factory.php` are actually the same apart from the url that gets called, you can do something like this:

`api_add_factory.php`

```
<?php

function callApi($url)
{
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($data);
}
```

`add_factory.php`

```
<?php

include("../../config/check.php");
include("../../api/api_add_factory.php"); //include web services

$url1 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/selectFactory?Fac_ID=$Fac_ID";
$url2 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/insertFactory?fac_id=$Fac_ID&fac_name=$Fac_ID";

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

  $Fac_ID = $_POST['Fac_ID'];

  $json1 = callApi($url1);
  $queryt = $json1->factoryList;

  if(empty($queryt)){

          $json2 = callApi($url2);

          if(!empty($json2)){

            header("Location:factory.php");

          }else{
            echo "
            <script>alert('Something wrong, please try again')</script>
            <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
            ";

          }
        }
  else{

      echo "
      <script>alert('The factory you want to add is already exist')</script>
      <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
      ";

  }
}
```

This way, we don't need to repeat the code of the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer? It is possible to merge "api_add_factory.php" and "api2_add_factory.php" into one php page?

Comment: Yes, look at my edit. I had the same idea after I saw the first version of my answer. You just need to pass a parameter to the function.

Comment: Why the url is at the add_factory.php? why just put it api_add_factory?

Comment: Because you need a parameter to call the same `callApi` function with two different URLs.

Comment: I already change the code with your latest answer, when I at "add_facory.php" error occur at this line:  $Fac_ID = $_POST['Fac_ID'];

Comment: Yes, I noticed a mistake in my second solution. The two functions weren't exactly the same in your code. I have made an edit to the answer.

Comment: Cannot dude, the error is still at this line: $Fac_ID = $_POST['Fac_ID'], at "add_factory.php"

Comment: I have no idea what that error is, but I don't think it was caused by my changes, because I didn't touch that line. And anyway, if you have an error, you should provide the error message rather that just saying "I have an error".

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Fac_ID in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ebooking\pages\manage_factory\add_factory.php on line 6

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Fac_ID in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ebooking\pages\manage_factory\add_factory.php on line 7

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Fac_ID in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ebooking\pages\manage_factory\add_factory.php on line 7

Comment: That's not an error, that's a notice. Notices are not errors, but warning, and they don't stop the execution of the program. Anyway, I am sorry but I don't think this has anything to do with my changes. Last but not least, please do not turn this into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377812/methods-to-remedy-a-chameleon-question-and-teach-the-op). Your first issue, handling the includes in a better way, has been answered. If you have further issues with your new code, the best way to proceed would be to open a new question.